# getUrl remove GET parameter from url

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, redirect, https, secure

I am trying to redirect user from https to http if user request nonsecure page from https.
I got solution for same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399485/redirect-https-to-http-on-non-secure-magento-pages), see solution provided by @user2432030 or @Johnboy

If secure URL has `GET` parameter like

```
https://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?ref=abd&q=demo
```

then `_getCurrentUnsecureUrl` returns URL

```
http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/
```

means nonsecure URL looses all GET parameter which break results.

How to fix `_getCurrentUnsecureUrl` function so it will return correct http URL?

PS. If anyone have better solution for my real problem ie. redirecting user from https to http if page is nonsecure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect the whole https-site to http you can do something like that in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On (should already be in your htaccess)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: if you "think" and dont "know" whats your problem how should we? :D pls describe it more in detail what you want

Comment: have you gone through stack overflow link I posted in question?